# Carriage Return in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I have a rather large python program, where I want to have a loading bar at the bottom of the terminal, and at the same time be able to display debug messages. Typical Linux package manager style.

I've made an example of such functionality in

```
from time import sleep


def print_load_bar(r, bar_length=20):
    bar = '\r['
    for i in range(bar_length):
        bar += '░' if i < r*bar_length else ' '

    bar += '] {} %'.format(round(100*r))

    print(bar, end='')


N = 20
msg = 'Debug message #{}'

for n in range(N):
    print('\r', msg.format(n))
    print_load_bar((n+1) / N)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Halfway this gives:

```
...
Debug message #11
Debug message #12
[░░░░░░░░░░    ] 65 %
```

And at the end:

```
...
Debug message #17
Debug message #18
Debug message #19
[░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 100 %
```

Does any of you know about a way to achieve this without the `\r` at the beginning of every print statement `print('\r', msg.format(n))`?

Comment: Do you want to make this from scratch or do you consider external libraries like [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar)?

Comment: There are ANSI escape sequences (assuming your terminal supports them) for doing more precise cursor positioning, as well as remembering the current cursor position and moving the cursor to the last remembered position, but you are probably better off using a library like `curses` to avoid terminal-specific code.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the library, Piinthesky! It would also be interesting to try to do as you say, Chepner :)